# Move ESXI Windows VMDK to PROXMOX

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, proxmox, clone

Long story short. HDD's broken. I only have the VMDK's on an Backup. I read through the [Migration of Server Wiki](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Migration_of_servers_to_Proxmox_VE) but they are all assume that I can access the VM. I can't. Is it possible, without reinstalling Windows, to import the VMDKS to Proxmox VE?

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation : https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Migration_of_servers_to_Proxmox_VE#VMware_to_Proxmox_VE_.28KVM.29

I never try this

Answer (score 0):

You got two question / problem there. A crash recovery problem and a migration question.

Before triing to move them to another hypervisor, use VMPlayer/VMware Workstation to restart them, and run the requiered migration tool/step after. (check @Dom answer for the link)

Comment: I'll try this, thanks! Didn't think of the VMPlayer to do this job.